# Getting MySQL results based on date by current month in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, date, codeigniter-3

I currently get the last 30 days results like this.

```
public function commission_month(){

$status = 'A';  

$this->db->select_sum('LenderCommission');
$this->db->where(['Status' => $status ]) ;
$this->db->where('CompletedDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ');
$query = $this->db->get('toutcome'); 
$result = $query->result();

return $result[0]->LenderCommission;   


}
```

What i am really trying to do is get results for this current month.
And then when its the next month , its should do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "like" query to get the information you need, assuming the dates are stored in a manner you can easily apply a like to.

Basically, the query will be something along the lines of `... AND CompletedDate LIKE 'YYYY-MM-%'...` where YYYY and MM are valid year and months.  This can be done in CodeIgniter by using the `$this->db->like()` builder:

```
$this->db->like('CompletedDate', date('Y-m'));
```

Your code then being:

```
public function commission_month(){

    $status = 'A';  

    $this->db->select_sum('LenderCommission');
    $this->db->where(['Status' => $status ]) ;
    $this->db->like('CompletedDate', date('Y-m'));
    $query = $this->db->get('toutcome'); 
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result[0]->LenderCommission;   
}
```

Comment: For check only month I used: 
$this->db->like('CompletedDate', '-' . date('m') . '-');